# Handling Events in method so the value can be picked up when completed in event so it doesn't return null each time

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, event-handling

I am trying to figure out the best practice for handling and correctly processing the following:
I have an inline method that in the process of the method adds an event handler process, but I need to figure out how to handle the rest of my method to wait until it receives data into that variable before proceeding (or if there is a better practice possibly)

Currently the method I am focused on is an inline method, so it finishes up and tries to return the data from the expected variable before it is assigned to it, so it returns 'null' because it is trying to return it before that event handler gets data to it.

Please let me know what the best practice / patterns are to handle / accomplish this.

Thank you.

[Code Sample]  The method I am calling and which is finishing and trying to return the 'recievedMsg' variable value before it is assigned...

```
    public T Recieve<T>(string routingKey)
    {
        T recievedMsg = default(T);

        try
        {
            _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: routingKey,
                                    durable: false,
                                    exclusive: false,
                                    autoDelete: false,
                                    arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);

            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                recievedMsg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message);
            };

            _channel.BasicConsume(queue: routingKey,
                                    noAck: true,
                                    consumer: consumer);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error Handling
        }

        return recievedMsg;
    }
```

[Call that is invoking the Method]

```
        var obj = new testObj()
        {
            Id = 123,
            Name = "Test McTesting",
            Dexcription = "Employee of the Month"
        };


        using (var rbt= new proxyClass("localhost"))
        {
           // .Recieve() method is completing too quickly so always returns null to employee 
           var employee = rbt.Recieve<testObj>("Test McTesting");
        }
```

Comment: create a event in ``rbt`` object's class and when recieved event fires you fire your own event

Comment: This looks like the RabbitMQ.Client library - Have you considered using EasyNetQ for Rabbit instead?   It has support for `async` and `await`, which you might find simpler than working directly with the `EventingBasicConsumer` -  https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question directly (about the pattern); I'd suggest using the Task Asynchronous Pattern (TAP).     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx

TAP allows you not only to handle a successful result, but also simplifies your exception handling; something which is less than trivial with a simple `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent`.

TAP also allows you to easily do things like add a timeout to your operation, or allow a user to cancel.

```
    public async Task<T> Recieve<T>(string routingKey)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: routingKey,
                                durable: false,
                                exclusive: false,
                                autoDelete: false,
                                arguments: null);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                var recievedMsg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message);

                // Tries to set the result.  Will fail if the task has been cancelled
                tcs.TrySetResult(recievedMsg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Tries to set the exception.  Will fail if the task has been cancelled
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        };

        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: routingKey,
                                noAck: true,
                                consumer: consumer);

        return await tcs.Task;
    }
```

Example usage (inside an `async` method)

```
    public async Task TestIt()
    {
        using (var rbt = new ProxyClass("localhost"))
        {
            var employee = await rbt.Recieve<TestObj>("Test McTesting");
            Console.WriteLine($"{employee.Id} / {employee.Name} / {employee.Dexcription}");
        }
    }
```

(Bonus: Example usage with timeout - this is one of the strengths of TAP)

```
    public async Task TestItWithTimeout()
    {
        using (var rbt = new ProxyClass("localhost"))
        {
            var task = rbt.Recieve<TestObj>("Test McTesting");

            if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))) == task)
            {
                var employee = await task;
                Console.WriteLine($"{employee.Id} / {employee.Name} / {employee.Dexcription}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: It's a good idea to put a `try..catch` inside the `EventingBasicConsumer.Received` handler because RabbitMq.Client's consumer thread won't handle the exception - the thread will just die.

If your Rabbit Consumer thread dies unexpectedly without you handling the error, your application will not have any way of knowing about it - All subsequent messages simply get left undelivered in your queue on the broker, and subsequent calls to your `Receive<T>` will just be left waiting forever.

Comment: Great answer, I appreciate your help.  Thank you.